# my .tar.gz files are converted into some files with [noeol][converted]

Tags: sql, backup, converters

while transferring the backup file though ftp server,, i got some problem ,, all .tar.gz file are converted into some files.. title with 'backup'

while i trying to open them in vi i got `"backup" [noeol][converted] 26168L, 12302861C`

may i know what is the problem ,, is it possible to return my file,, how to convert them again in ssh..

i dont have any other backup i have reinstalled my server ,, there is no i need to return them , plz try to help

Comment: Why are you using vi? .tar.gz files should be opened with the tar and/or gzip commands

Comment: folder is converted into file ,, i cant open that backup file using cd so i try to open in vi ,,

Comment: What folder? Please rephrase your question or add some screenshots